# Can't make a virtual env in PyCharm using a WSL Python interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use a Python interpreter in WSL to make virtual environments, buy it doesn't show any Python file.

I used `where python3` to find the interpreter. It says `/usr/bin/python3` but as you can see it shows nothing in PyCharm.

[image]

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling PyCharm and it didn't work.

Also when I create a virtual env from WSL terminal using `virtualenv -p python3 venv` I can't import that in PyCharm because it doesn't recognize Python in `~/venv/bin/...`

Comment: did you try the WSL button under vagrant?

Comment: yes. that is main python interpreter and not a virtual env

Comment: I am not familiar with WSL, but I do use SSH interpreter, and with my experience I know it doesn't really support it in pycharm. The workaround I use is to first set up new venv manually on my server, and then set it as the interpreter through pycharm. If it helps you I'll post it as an answer

Comment: thanks if you do. I think it can be done by set up a venv on wsl and then set it as interpreter through ssh, as you told.

Answer (score 9):

You can set up venv inside wsl:

```
python3 -m venv /usr/venv/project1
```

And add this to pycharm:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, Virtual Environments are not yet supported in Pycharm with WSL.  See the docs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html).

Excerpt: "Note that with WSL you cannot create virtual environments: all packages you install will be added to the corresponding system interpreter. You will be asked to enter your sudo password"

If I absolutely need to code against a library within Ubuntu (such as Apache Pulsar), I use Linux Pycharm running an XSession to XFCE, running withing WSL.  It works very well and you will find lots of articles to achieve this with a Google Search.

Comment: hows the speed, is it laggy with xsession?

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with using WSL through PyCharm, but I do use an  interpreter on remote server thourgh SSH.
With my experience I know PyCharm doesn't support creating a new `venv` environment from the IDE on the remote server.

The workaround I use is to first set up new `venv` manually within the server, and then when I set up the project interpreter in PyCharm I set the interpreter path to the relevant `venv` path in the server.
So I suggest the same thing- first create a new `venv` on the WSL environment and then set the path of the `venv` as the project interpreter (through WSL no through remote server)

Comment: can you explain a bit more on this? I am trying to do the same with no success. when configuring the python interpreter I put in the path ananconda/envs/bin/python3 but then when I run the scripts pycharm keeps using anaconda/bin/python3

Comment: after setting up a new interpreter using the new env through the pychram/project setting you need to edit the run configurations (near the play button) to use the new interpreter. (run configuration and interpreter configurations are separate things, and one can use the other)

Comment: I already have venv on WSL , but when trying to add in Pycharm it doesn't show the `python` file. I can't choose the `python` file. i see other files.

Answer (score 1):

What I do, is create a virtual env manuall `python3 -m venv venv` and then in PyCharm I set the python interpreter from the virtual env created. It works, the only painful point is when you add mopre packages, you would need to invalidate caches.